# Custom deserialization

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have collection with thousands of documents, in document there's field named **Rate**, problem is currently its type is string, so when it's not available, the old developer set it to "N/A". For now I want to change the type of this field to numeric in C# (set it to 0 when n/a), but if I do so I can't load the past data.
Can we customize the deserialization so it will convert N/A to 0?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to create an `IBsonSerializer` or `SerializerBase<>` and attach it to the property you wish to serialize using the `BsonSerializerAttribute`. Something like the following:

```
public class BsonStringNumericSerializer : SerializerBase<double>
{
    public override double Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        var type = context.Reader.GetCurrentBsonType();
        if (type == BsonType.String)
        {
            var s = context.Reader.ReadString();
            if (s.Equals("N/A", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                return 0.0;
            }
            else
            {
                return double.Parse(s);
            }
        }
        else if (type == BsonType.Double)
        {
            return context.Reader.ReadDouble();
        }
        // Add any other types you need to handle
        else
        {
            return 0.0;
        }
    }
}

public class YourClass
{
    [BsonSerializer(typeof(BsonStringNumericSerializer))]
    public double YourDouble { get; set; }
}
```

If you don't want to use attributes you can create an `IBsonSerializationProvider` and register it using `BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializationProvider`.

Full documentation of MongoDB C# Bson serialization can be found [here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/bson/serialization/)