# MongoDB C#: How to automatically pad strings with zeros

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, formatting, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a small web application on ASP.Net. It uses MongoDB as database. I have the following classes.

```
public class ClassA
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
    ...
    public List<ClassC> ListC { get; set; }
}

public class ClassC
{
    public string PropertyD { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

ClassA is serialized in MongoDB. I have a task to make `PropertyA`, `PropertyB` and `PropertyD` to padded with zeros in DB, e.g. `256` should be `00000000256`. There are different widths for each property. I know that I can create a custom serializer, but as far as I know Mongo custom serializers are parameterless. I want to have a flexible solution for this, because in future I can get a similar task for other properties for other classes with different widths of zeros

Comment: Can you talk us through why you want to do this?

Comment: Basically this is the wish of my manager

Comment: Have a squiz at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42382064/34092 - would that technique work for you?