# C# MongoDB Serialization Converting Property "ReadBsonType can only be called when State is Type, not when State is Value."

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb.driver

I have a model that I'm trying to deserialize, the problem is that on one of the properties, it's sometimes a string and sometimes a document.  So I decided to write a custom serializer which builds from SerializerBase.  However, it seems there might be a bug in the framework.  When overriding the Deserialize method, I always get the exception "ReadBsonType can only be called when State is Type, not when State is Value."

I'm using .Net framework 4.6.2 and all version of my mongo libraries are 2.8.0

This is a simplified version of my class and how I'm implementing it.

```
public class MyClassSerializer : SerializerBase<string>
{
    public override string Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        // ultimately I will have some logic here but for now just trying to get this to not throw an error.
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Here's the model I'm trying to deserialize:

```
public class FormData
{
    [BsonId]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonSerializer(typeof(MyClassSerializer))]
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

This seems like a very out-of-the-box solution, can anyone see what I might be doing wrong?  Also because I'm trying to write a custom serializer that can handle type conversion, is there maybe a more appropriate way of accomplishing this?

Thank you!

Edit: Below is the stack trace I am getting:

> at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.DeserializeMemberValue(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonMemberMap memberMap) at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.DeserializeClass(BsonDeserializationContext context) at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args) at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Deserialize[TValue](IBsonSerializer`1 serializer, BsonDeserializationContext context) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.CursorBatchDeserializationHelper.DeserializeBatch[TDocument](RawBsonArray batch, IBsonSerializer`1 documentSerializer,

Comment: Where does the exception happen, what line of code?  Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42336751/custom-deserialization and http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/bson/serialization/

Comment: Hi Jon, I did see this, I actually adopted my code from this example. But even implementing as the poster did, I still get the exception.  I've updated my post to include the stack trace so you can see where in the framework it's calling my code.

Comment: I don't see MyClassSerializer anywhere in that stack trace? Is that the whole thing?

Comment: I believe that's because "DeserializeMemberValue" of the framework calls my code and the exception is being thrown after my method already returns

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
public class MyClass {
public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
[BsonSerializer(typeof(MyCustomStringSerializer))]
public string X { get; set; }
}

BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MyClass>(cm => {
cm.AutoMap();
cm.GetMemberMap(c => c.X).SetSerializer(new MyCustomStringSerializer());
});
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for answering. While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

What about change you class to an object? I got similar problem and it works.

```
public object myObject { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment Rogerio, it does get past the error but gets automatically converted to a IDictionary<string,string>.  This would definitely be a workaround, but would like to not have any post deserialization steps to perform.  Also, would like to know how to solve this in case in the future I am forced to use a custom serializer

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing the serializer for the model itself instead of the specific property and this now works.

Comment: Could you share more details of your solution please?