# MongoDB C# driver: Class model for variable schema?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I've got a mongo database filled with a load of GeoJSON. Some documents look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d652136f39c50fbe859018e"),
    "properties" : {
        "theme" : "Administrative Boundaries"
}}
```

And others look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d652131f39c50fbe858f017"),
    "properties" : {
        "theme" : [ 
            "Land"
        ]
}}
```

I.e. in some documents theme is a single string, in others it's an array.

I was hoping the following property in my class would automatically handle both:

```
public string[] Theme { get; set; }
```

However mongo errors when it encounters the first JSON example.

How should I design my class model to handle this? Currently I'm planning to use a raw BsonElement like this:

```
public BsonValue Theme { get; set; }
```

And then write another property to parse it. I want to be able to query this property as well using the LINQ provider.

Comment: is running a data migration/ transformation on the db to make everything the same schema an option? i.e. make every theme field a single string or an array with an update command.

Comment: @RyanGunner It's possible, but the dataset is massive (~45GB) so that would take hours if not days.

Comment: in that case, give a custom serializer a try as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42382064/4368485) but i'm not sure how that's going to solve the problem of writing a single linq query for all the variants of the docs.